# FFMPEG : Merge 4 files each one including : 1 video + 1 audio + 1 subtitle (eng) + 1 subtitle (esp)

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

I need to merge TV chapters (24) split into 4 pieces.

Each one has :

1 Video stream, 
1 Audio stream, 
2 Subtitle (SRT) streams.

MKVtoolnix is useless here because some are,  AVC/Opus another one is VP9/Vorbis , so I found recoded is needed here!

I've successfully merged Video and Audio but unable to do with SRT option.

Can someone help me to fix it?